How to add dll security file into canoe?
I already have the dll file but how to add that into canoe and use them?
i have added the dll file into the canoe location (Diagnostic/ISO TP ->Diagnostic layer->security Access) . but when iam trying to call the function in my capl script its showing erroe like unknown function. iam using canoe 17 version.
Thanks in advance.

Post the error message. Which functions are in your DLL? Do they comply to the signature expected by CANoe?

iam using capl inbuild function DiagStartGenerateKeyFromSeed()

Again: Post the error message. Which functions are in your DLL? Do they comply to the signature expected by CANoe?

Try adding the .dll file in CANoe -> Options -> Programming -> CAPL DLL. If this doesn't work try adding it directly from the node configuration of the node that you intend to use the security functions.
